# UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: lag my app seriously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

I have a tableview. It will receive mess of data from server. Every time tableview receive data I wanna it show the latest one at bottom.I called         `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` but it lag my app i can do nothing else in my screen when scroll to bottom of tableview.
Here is my main code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"tableViewCell";

    DLtestCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    NSDictionary* dict = arr[indexPath.row];
    cell.myLabel.attributedText = dict[@"content"];
    [cell.myImageview sd_setImageWithURL:dict[@"imageUrl"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentPlaceHolder"]];    
    return cell;
}
```

and here is scrolling to the bottom main code

```
- (void)reloadTableView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSIndexPath *lastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[lastRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    });
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: try to reload in main thread (performOnMainThread) method

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method.

And in viewWillAppear write below code.

```
[theTableView reloadData];    
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:sectionNumberHere];
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

here 'rowNumber' is the row number in the data source you want to scroll to.

or you can calculate 'rowNumber' as follows:

```
int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
```

and pass this lastRowNumber to indexPathForRow.

NOTE : numberOfRowsInSection returns row count, not the last row number (which is row count - 1).

Comment: actually i am doing like this, but there are mess of data access it cause i can't operate anything